# FileException in UploadedFile.php line 235:

Tags: php, laravel-5.1

I tried to upload an image file into a specified folder..

But it shows an Error like this

```
FileException in UploadedFile.php line 235:
The file "download (1).jpg" was not uploaded due to an unknown error.
```

My controller function is something like this

```
function postSave( Request $request)
{

    $rules = $this->validateForm();
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules);  
    if ($validator->passes()) {
        $data = $this->validatePost('tb_hotel');

        $id = $this->model->insertRow($data , $request->input('hotel_id'));

        if(!is_null(Input::file('logo')))
        {
            $updates = array();
            $file = $request->file('logo');
            $destinationPath = public_path().'/uploads/hotels/';
            $filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();
            $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension(); //if you need extension of the file
             $newfilename = $id.'.'.$extension;
             // print_r($newfilename);exit;
            $uploadSuccess = $request->file('logo')->move($destinationPath, $newfilename);
            if( $uploadSuccess ) {
                $updates['logo'] = $newfilename; 
            } 
            $this->model->insertRow($updates , $id );
        }   
        .
        .
        .
        .           

}
```

I don't know why!!.. I'm using the same function in another controller there it works properly..

But here it show me an error like I mention above..

Someone please help me..

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps using the already created $file and stripping out certain characters from the Filename does the trick for you.

```
    <?php

        function postSave( Request $request) {
            $rules      = $this->validateForm();
            $validator  = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules);
            if ($validator->passes()) {
                $data   = $this->validatePost('tb_hotel');

                $id     = $this->model->insertRow($data, $request->input('hotel_id'));

                if (!is_null(Input::file('logo'))) {
                    $updates         = array();
                    $file            = $request->file('logo');                      //<== YOU ALREADY HAVE THIS VARIABLE HERE....
                    $destinationPath = public_path() . '/uploads/hotels/';
                    $filename        = $file->getClientOriginalName();
                    $extension       = $file->getClientOriginalExtension(); //if you need extension of the file

                    //CLEAN UP THE FILE NAME...
                    $newfilename     = trim( preg_replace("#[\(\)\[\]]#", "_", ($id . '.' . $extension)) );

                    $uploadSuccess  = $file->move($destinationPath, $newfilename);  //<== USE THE $file VARIABLE HERE...
                    if ($uploadSuccess) {
                        $updates['logo'] = $newfilename;
                    }
                    $this->model->insertRow($updates, $id);
                }

            }
        }
```

Comment: There is no change occur..After using your code...It shows the same error